# WPF C# adding to window

Tags: c#, wpf

how can I add a `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox()` to my window or grid. Without having to add a `WindowsFormsHost()`. Here is my code:

.xaml

```
             <Grid Name="Grid1">
             </Grid>
        </Window>
```

.xaml.cs

```
        Host1 = new WindowsFormsHost();
        Host1.Margin = new Thickness(8, 12, 3, 3);
        Host1.Height = 315;
        Host1.Width = 570;
        Host1.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        Host1.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;

        richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        richTextBox1.Height = 315;
        richTextBox1.Width = 570;
        richTextBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(richTextBox1_TextChanged);

        Host1.Child = richTextBox1;
        Grid1.Children.Add(Host1);
```

I want to remove my `Host1` it makes the code too troublesome. How can I add directly to the window the `richTextBox1` or directly to the `Grid1` the `richTextBox1`?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite simple: don't use the Windows Forms version of the control.

Instead look to use the [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) included in System.Windows.Controls, or the [free RichTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RichTextBox&referringTitle=Home) from the Community Edition of the WPF Toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Windows Forms and WPF are two completely different technologies with completely different infrastructures, rendering stacks, event models, input models, etc.

To host WinForms controls in WPF pages, you need something to host the WinForms control(s) and bridge the gaps between WPF and WinForms, marshalling events, etc. Conversely, to host WPF controls in WinForms pages, you have to use the [ElementHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

You might want to consider using WPF's [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) control instead.

Alternatively, if you find the WinForms RichText control too troublesome, consider using one of the many WPF RichText controls available from a number of vendors / sources.

Comment: Is there a `control()` version of `windowsformhose()` ?

Comment: Actually do you know how to implement it using `ElementHost` ?

Comment: Why do you want to use the WinForms RichText control rather than the WPF one?